# FrameLayout sliding menu

Tags: android, layout

I am developing an Android application which uses a `framelayout`, in which there are two views inflated:

- Upper view holds the main functions of the applications;
- Lower view holds a refreshable list implemented with "pull down to refresh" function.

The upper view is moved to the right so that you can see the lower view containing the list, but when I start to do the pull down to refresh action, the upper view returns itself back to left covering the lower view containing the list. The list gets refreshed, but I don't want the upper view to behave this way, covering the lower one.
I would like to know if there is a way to freeze the upper view until the user does some other action (button clicking) to return it back over the lower view.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final FrameLayout main = new FrameLayout(this);

    menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offerlist, null);
    app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

    main.addView(menu);
    main.addView(app);
    setContentView(main);

    Display display = (Display) ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay();
    final int width = display.getWidth();
    final float wDip = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 70, this.getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());
            ...

            app.startAnimation(hide);
            menuw = (int) (width - wDip);
    app.offsetLeftAndRight(-menuw);
```

Thank you in advance.